# 'drive' does not exist on type 'typeof client'

Tags: angular, google-drive-api

Angular 5 cannot find `drive` from `gapi.client`. What I have done is:

`package.json`:

```
"@types/gapi.client.drive": "^3.0.0",
```

`tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"types": ["gapi.auth2", "gapi.client", "gapi.client.drive"]
```

`index.html`:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Both my editor(VS Code) and Angular report an error like below:

`Property 'drive' does not exist on type 'typeof client'`

, but `console.log(gapi.client.drive.files);` can get everything I need.

Am I missing any library here?

Comment: Don't really use Angular, but just judging from the error, the Drive API library isn't loaded yet when the call was made. So try to make sure all libraries are loaded before using their methods.

Comment: @noogui You're talking about a runtime error. The error reported by the OP appears to me to be a compilation error. The TypeScript compiler sees a type for `gapi.client` that does not include a `drive` property and emits an error. I ran into this issue too but installing `@types/gapi.client.drive` took care of it.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you install the all these plugins.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
npm install --save @types/gapi.client.drive
```

and in tsconfig.app.json
in compileroptions section

```
"types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2" ,"gapi.client", "gapi.client.drive"]
```

and in index.html file you need to add this js.

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was the one that fixed it for me, specifically compilerOptions.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve this problem of `gapi` and `gapi.auth` in Angular is by installing the type script definitions using NPM.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

In `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` within `compilerOptions` section add this `"gapi", "gapi.auth2"` to `types`. It will look like

```
"types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2"],
```

Then in you service or component, use `NgZone`, you import it from `@angular/core`

Here is example:

```
import { Component, NgZone, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-app',
  templateUrl: './google-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-app.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleAppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
        // example to render login button
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        ...
        ...
        });

        // example to load client
        gapi.load('client', {
         ...
         ...
        });

    });
  }    
}
```

Angular NgZone documentation... [read more](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

In **index.html**, depending what you want, you may need to add the following within the `<head></head>` tag

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing `@types/gapi.client.sheets` solved this issue for me